# Writing text on the border of an A4 PDF in R

Tags: r, pdf-generation

I need to write on a PDF device on the extreme border of the page. With this snippet:

```
pdf('foo.pdf')          #Write next plot to foo.pdf in current dire 
par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))  #Set numbers of lateral blank lines to zero
par(xaxs='i', yaxs='i') #Does not extend axes by 4 percent for pretty labels 
plot.new()              #Create a blank plot, as we just want to write our text  
text(0, .5, "hello", pos=4, offset=0) #Write to the right with no default 0.5 offset
dev.off()               #Close device, that is saving for a PDF device
```

I get a `foo.pdf` with `hello` on the extreme left in the middle of the page, as intended,that is:

[image]

Unfortunately, if I set the paper output as `paper='a4'`, that is:

```
pdf('foo.pdf', paper='a4') #note the A4 setting 
par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
par(xaxs='i', yaxs='i' )
plot.new()
text(0, .5, "hello", pos=4, offset=0)
dev.off()
```

`hello` isn't put on the border anymore, but:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `paper` is set to something else than `"special"`, argument `pagecentre` becomes relevant. If you set it to `FALSE`, then the offset disappears.

```
pdf('foo.pdf', paper='a4', pagecentre=FALSE)
par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
par(xaxs='i', yaxs='i' )
plot.new()
text(0, .5, "hello", pos=4, offset=0)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Your approach works for the 0-border but not for the 1-border. With paper A4, `text(0, 1, "hello", pos=4, offset=0)` will be at about 75% of the page height. The worst is that every text where `y>1` (or `x>1`) is anyway considered out of the border and not printed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can confirm it doesn't work for me too; it looks like a bug IMHO.

A workaround for your problem is to set the A4 paper dimensions directly in the `pdf` call:

```
pdf('foo.pdf', width=8.3, height=11.7) #we set A4 dimensions of 8.3 x 11.7 inches
par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
par(xaxs='i', yaxs='i' )
plot.new()
text(0, .5, "hello", pos=4, offset=0)
dev.off()
```