# How to print or cat text into pdf() in R without markdown

Tags: r, pdf, export-to-pdf

I'm creating a PDF file with some plots, but I want to also include some text message at the bottom. For reasons beyond my control, I cannot install a latex distribution on this system, so I can't knit a markdown file, but have to use `pdf()`.

When I just use `print` or `cat` nothing shows up in the pdf. I tried using `sink()` based on the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940526/print-text-message-to-pdf-from-r), but that didn't work either:

```
pdf("filename.pdf")
sink("filename.pdf")
print("message")
sink()
dev.off()
```

No error message was received, but the file created has no pages.

Any ideas? I'm considering a workaround of just plotting a text only plot, but I'm hoping there's a more reasonable solution.

Comment: Can [this be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525698/saving-a-text-box-to-pdf-in-r) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168471/writing-text-on-the-border-of-an-a4-pdf-in-r)?

Comment: @PoGibas yeah, that looks like my planned workaround solution - creating a plot and just populating it with text.

Comment: I'm guessing you have other things going on with your system and latex, but I just thought I'd mention that one of the things I've liked about [**tinytex**](https://yihui.name/tinytex/) is that it can be installed even without admin privileges.

Comment: Can you install any software?  If you can install pandoc (or numerous other utilities that convert html to pdf) write your report out as html and then convert it. In particular check whether you already have such a utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We simply could plot the text with `text` in `pdf` device. `text` only works after a `plot` call. That we don't have to deactivate everything, we call `plot.new` which is basically an empty plot. Look into `?pdf` and `?text` options for further customizing.

```
txt <- "message"

pdf("filename2.pdf", paper="a4")
plot.new()
text(x=.1, y=.1, txt)  # first 2 numbers are xy-coordinates within [0, 1]
text(.5, .5, txt, font=2, cex=1.5)
text(.9, .9, txt, font=4, cex=2, col="#F48024")
dev.off()
```

[image]

For the `sink` solution rather use `cat` and add a carriage return `\r` at the very end of the text to obtain a valid last line for `pdf` processing of the `.txt` file.

```
sink("filename.txt")  # to be found in dir `getwd()`
cat("message\r")
sink()

pdf("filename.pdf")  # ditto
plot.new()
text(.5, .5, readLines("filename.txt"))
dev.off()
```

Customize with different `x` and `y` coordinates, `font` options, and `paper` formatting in `pdf` call.

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Why do we need the whole `sink()` part? Can't I just put the text directly into the plot?

Comment: @iod You started with `sink`. Probably this is possible, just replace `readLines("filename.txt")` with `"message"`.  `sink` is designed to direct console output in to a `.txt` file, I got the impression you wanted something like this.

Comment: I tried with sink because I came across an answer that suggested I could use it. No reason to use it if it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I was planning on doing, was hoping for a simpler solution. Appreciate the detailed guide.

Comment: @jay.sf Hi, wondering how can we create a new page?

Comment: @MathAvengers Another `plot.new();text(...)` will create a new page. Use `dev.off()` just once at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

I had success solving this problem (PDFs only and R/RStudio but not RMarkdown) by using the package `qpdf`, specifically the `pdf_overlay_stamp()` function.

```
#Set WD
setwd("INSERT PATH FOR DESIRED INPUT FILES AND OUTPUT FILE")

#Generate Sample Files
pdf("Part1.pdf", width = 8.5, height = 11)
plot.new()
text(x = 0.35, y = 1, adj = c(0,1), labels = "This is Part1.pdf")
dev.off()

pdf("Part2.pdf", width = 8.5, height = 11)
plot.new()
text(x = 0.35, y = 0.5, adj = c(0,1), labels = "This is Part2.pdf")
dev.off()

#Identify files to overlay
f1 <- "Part1.pdf"
f2 <- "Part2.pdf"

#Overlay Text
qpdf::pdf_overlay_stamp(input = f1, stamp = f2)
```

If you already have source PDFs just substitute `f1` and `f2` for the file names of the base file and the stamp/watermark that you wish to overlay onto the base file.

Please note that `pdf_overlay_stamp()` pulls all pages from the `f1/input file` but only the 1st page from `f2/stamp file`.

You will need to change the x and y values for the plot for the "Part1.pdf" to change the placement of your desired text.